# xCode ld library not found in release mode and duplicate symbols in debug mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, linker-errors

I'm developing an iOS app using xCode 6.3. This project uses Cocoapods for a number of libraries. I always open the xcode workspace, not the project file.

When I build the app in debug mode, I get 300+ duplicate symbol errors which of course causes the build to fail. To remedy this, I removed the libpods.a from the "Link binary with Libraries" list and then it works. But now when I go to archive it for upload to the app store, it fails with an "ld: library not found for -lPods-Mixpanel" error.

If I add libpods.a back to the list, I can archive it, but then I can't build it in debug mode.

I've checked all the settings multiple times and I can't see where there's any difference between the debug and release modes.

How can I fix this problem or get more information to debug it?

Edit: Here are the flags from my project

Other librarian flags: $(OTHER_LDFLAGS)

Other linker flags: $(inherited)

Xcode evaluates both of these and fills them in, but I can't copy or view the full text. Here's a screenshot.

[linker flags screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3p86og95e9pknvj/Screen%20Shot%202015-06-30%20at%208.55.30%20AM.png?dl=0)

Comment: Did `pod install` come up with anything weird?

Comment: Can you show the build settings (e.g OTHER_LDFLAGS) from your project and from the pods projects?